# Gift wrap option in cart page

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

We have an eCommerce website for Gifts, We need the customer to select products from diffrent suppliers to Wrap it as a gift.

How can we add gift options in cart page and add price for wrapping?

Answer (score 0):

Please have look below extension with following Features:

https://marketplace.magento.com/globalecomservices-gift-wrapper.html

https://www.magestore.com/magento-gift-wrap-extension.html

https://amasty.com/magento-gift-wrap.html

Gift wrap extension enables the customers to select gift wrap options while purchasing the products.

Buyers can add appropriate gift message using the gift wrap extension.
Multiple gift wrap options with different colored wrappers can be provided for the users.
Maximum number of characters for the gift message can be 150 characters.

Gift wrap extension can be added either in Cart Page OR CMS page.

Gift Wrap extension is Mobile Responsive and it supports all Mobile devices.

This extension can be easily used as extra fee module for Rush orders.

Extension can be installed quickly and ready to add gift wrap feature in your website within minutes.

I Hope it's helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks, I need to add it without extensions Can you help ?

Comment: You need to customization  according to your requirement, Magento CE have default feature please visit below URL, but only have Gift Message @Mohammad Badawy

Comment: follow this link- http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/marketing/gift-options.html